# Products stays on category pages where i deleted them

Tags: magento2

I try to move a product to one category, but it stay's on the category's that it was before.

[image]

But it shows up on "kleding", and it doesn't has to.

[image]

Comment: did you reindex?

Comment: did you rebuild the indexes? Also the second image has no meaning since we have no idea what the product is

Comment: Yes, did a reindex.. The second image, was to show that it is still there.